# Why get error `s is not defined` when excute javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in my typescript file (also a compiled javascript file):
s here is a global variable from external javascript file.

```
declare var s: any;
function setValue() {
    if (s) {
        s.value = 'authenticated';
    }
}
```

But when excute it will throw

> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined.

Need to change to `if (typeof s !== 'undefined')`. But I remember `if(s)` should also work. Anyone knows why?

If I do:

```
    function setValue() {
    let s;
      if (s) {
        s.value = 'authenticated';
      }
    }
```

It's working fine. But s here is also undfined.

Comment: Because `s` is not defined ?

Comment: You did not define "s" used within your if statement

Comment: Where did you define variable s?? what is it's scope? The error indicates that it is undefined, you may have defined it else where and which is not available in the the place where you are using it.

Comment: *"But I remember if(s) should also work"* ... not if it has never been declared anywhere or is out of scope

Comment: It's typescript, s if from external, update the question.

Comment: You declared the variable. It's still not defined.

Comment: But if I do let s; before if(s) it won't throw error, even if s still undefined now.

Comment: not defined !== undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the updated question, you are running into the issue that "undefined" can arise for two reasons in JavaScript:

1. `undefined` is a JavaScript data type with one value, `undefined`.

   - Function which don't explicitly return a value implicitly return `undefined` instead.
   - Variables which have been declared but never initialized have `undefined` as their value.
   - Function arguments that have not been supplied or replaced with default values have `undefined` as their value.
   - Non-existent object properties return `undefined` when read (including accessing Array elements that have never been set).
   - You can assign `undefined` to a variable.

   So the following examples all leave `a` set to undefined, and `typeof a` will evaluate to "undefined":

   ```
       var a;
       a = function() {}();  // function returning undefined;
       let b;
       a = b;    // uninitialized variable b has value undefined
       b = {};
       a = b.noSuchProperty;  // undefined returned for non existent property
       a = undefined;  // assign the undefined data type.
   ```
2. The string value "undefined" is also returned when the `typeof` operator is applied to a variable hat has not been declared within scope of the code. This **does not** mean the variable exists with a value and data type of `undefined`.

   ```
       // s has not been declared in scope
       console.log( typeof s);  // logs "undefined"
       if(s) // throws a ReferenceError, s not in scope
       // following code
   ```

As you have found, there is a big difference between the two. Attempting to access an "undefined" variable in the sense it does not exist within the scope of executing code throws a run time error.

Answer (score 1):

`declare` is a TypeScript keyword used to tell the compiler that there is a variable in the global scope it doesn't know about. `let`, on the contrary, actually defines a variable.

What that means for you is that when you `declare var s: any`, you're informing TypeScript that `s` exists elsewhere, and it will work on runtime. But since `s` is not defined somewhere else in the global scope, it won't actually work.

The reason `let s` does work is because you're actually using real JavaScript to say: "let JS know that there is a variable called S that I want to use later. It's value is `undefined`, but that's ok, because at least it exists." When you run the code, you'll find that your `if` statement won't execute, because `s` exists, but is `undefined`.